# how do i get rid of this overflow issue?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

on this page (http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com), when the page width is < 400px there is some extra room on the right that i'd like to get rid of.

here's the media query

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    #nav {
        height: 30px;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding-top: 9px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    #nav span {
        color: #272732;
        letter-spacing: .192em;
        font-family: "brandon-grotesque",Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-transform: uppercase ;
    }
    }
```

any ideas? overflow or margin issue?

Comment: it has to do with width of image.

Comment: @GCyrillus could you specify what image? thanks!

Comment: your images in between text , they do not shrink/resize  early enough.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with the images under 400px.

Comment: Wait, strange, it doesn't do it any more ... i guess all files are loaded now. To help cure this scroll would be usinng box-sizing:border-box; on your elements (it includes borders and padding to width set in CSS;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, your nav has nothing to do with this. I've located one element that is causing this: `#footnote` has a calculated width of 475px at viewport of 400px. You can easily fix this one by using `box-sizing: border-box;` on that element (with the -moz- and -webkit- prefixes in addition). Fixing this div fixes most of your whitespace issue.

The rest of the additional space seems to be caused by your `.text` and `.intro` divs. At 400px viewport, `.text` are a total of 410px wide and `.intro` is 420px, which appears to be some margin and/or padding. You can do similar to above by using box-sizing or shrink the width.

If you go the `box-sizing` route, which I highly recommend for responsive design because it accounts for padding and borders when calculating width, you'll need to increase the padding to give your text some room to breathe.

Comment: Actually, this is it :)